# How do I boot a USB-CD/DVD Drive from the GRUB?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, dvd

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 and want to install Windows 7 alongside it, but the BIOS is locked down and as such won't boot of a USB-DVD Drive with the Windows 7 Boot CD in it plugged in.

The question is, How do I boot off the CD in this drive from the GRUB, if it is possible at all?

Comment: Usually there is a second or two between turning the computer on and the appearance of the GRUB menu.  In that brief time, tap the F2 key. That should bring up the BIOS and you can change boot order to try to boot first from CD/DVD or USB before the HDD.

Comment: It also seem to generally work better to first install Windows and then install Ubuntu. Make a backup of your Ubuntu before anything so if it goes badly you have a means to recover what you currently have.

Comment: The BIOS is locked down, so there is no way to edit it directly.  That's why I want to boot via GRUB.  I'm also going to repair-install after installing Windows, that should restore the GRUB.